# How to: database versioning with maven2?

Tags: mysql, maven-2, versioning

I am finding any maven plugin for versioning database changes.

Comment: Are there any new updates/tools/techniques/practices to do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are a few plugins that offer some support for this task:

- [Maven LiquiBase Plugin](http://www.liquibase.org/manual/maven)
- [Maven Database Migration Plugin](http://code.google.com/p/c5-db-migration/)
- [DbMaintain Maven Plugin](http://source.mysema.com/display/maven/Maven+Plugins#MavenPlugins-dbmaintainmavenplugin) (a plugin for [DbMaintain](http://dbmaintain.sourceforge.net/overview.html), the famous tool from Unitils)

I don't have much experience with them, we currently use a custom tool to apply our change scripts. But the [Maven Database Migration Plugin](http://code.google.com/p/c5-db-migration/) is a serious candidate to replace it. LiquiBase is pretty famous but also different, changes are described in a generic XML format. About DbMaintain, it works well (in Unitils)  but I've never tested the wrapper plugin mentioned above.

Answer (score 6):

Here is one more, it's simple to use and has excellent support for Mysql stored procedures:

[Flyway Maven Plugin](http://flywaydb.org)

Answer (score 1):

I used this one http://jsoftware.org/maven-dbpatch-plugin

It supports rollback patches too.